# Prove that if k is odd and G is a k-regular (k-1)-edge-connected graph, then G has a perfect matching.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I understand that if k is odd and G is k-regular, then each vertex must have odd degree. I am having trouble understanding how to incorporate the edge-connectivity.

(This is my first undergraduate graph theory class, so a simple explanation would be helpful.)

Thanks!

Comment: What tools do you know to prove that a graph has a perfect matching?

Comment: To second @MishaLavrov's question, what theorems on matching have you learned? e.g., have to learned any of Tutte, Hall, ect

Comment: I have learned Hall's Theorem. My professor has also taught Tutte's Theorem, but I am still struggling with learning it. Should I go back and review Tutte's Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $k$ could be even and odd and theorem holds.

We can use Tutte's theorem to prove the result.

Let $S \subset V(G)$, and $odd(G/S)$ the number of odd components in $G-S$.

Then the number of edges out of $S$ is at most $|S|*k$. Now consider an odd component $O$ in $G-S$, we have:
$$ k*|O|=\sum_{v \in V(O)}deg(v) = 2|In|+|Out| $$
Here $|Out|$ denotes the number of edges with only one end in $O$ and $In$ denotes the number of edges with both end in $O$. Now because $|O|$ is odd so $k$ has the same parity as $|Out|$.

**Edit:** Now $|Out| \geq k-1$, so $|Out| \geq k$(here we use the fact that $|Out|$ and $k$ has the same parity).

**to** Now $|Out| \geq k-1$, so $|Out| \geq k$(here we use the fact that $|Out|$ and $k$ has the same parity). So thanks to the comment due to @Misha, we realized that $|Out| \geq k-1$ is true if $k$ is odd. Otherwise $|Out|$ could be even and hence equals to $0$ and then the argument breaks.

Now the number of edges with one end in an odd component and one end in $S$ is at least $k|odd(G-S)|$ which is also less than or equals to $|S|*k$. So $|S| \geq |odd(G-S)|$. So by Tutte's theorem the graph has a perfect matching.

Comment: We want $k$ to be odd to exclude graphs with an odd number of vertices.

Comment: The result shows that as long as the graph is k regular k-1 edge connected then it has a perfect matching which implies that the graph has an even number of vertices

Comment: So odd cycles don't exist?

Comment: Specifically, graphs with an odd number of vertices fail the test when $S = \varnothing$. Here, we can't conclude $|Out| \ge k-1$, so the argument doesn't apply.

Comment: Sir, I edited it. So I guess my argument in the comment was wrong. I think the issue is to guarantee that there are edges with only one end in the odd component. Cause then the argument would wok. And Happy new year. Merry Christmas. Can't believe time fly so fast.

Comment: The case where the number of vertices is odd - and $S = \varnothing$ - is actually the only case where the argument fails for even $k$. When $S$ is bigger, there must be at least $k-1$ edges between $O$ and $S$.